# git add/commit/push loses non-added items

Tags: git

My `git status` command showed two subdirs not staged for commit, each with some files.  I did a `git add -A` against one of the subdirs, and then a `git commit` and `git push`.

Now when I do a `git status` it says I'm up to date and have a clean working tree.  But that other directory hasn't been committed/pushed.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a git UI or just command line?

Comment: Just straight command line.

Comment: No `stash` made?

Comment: No, there was no stash.

Comment: Nothing was commited by mistake? `git add -A` adds all the files in the working tree. `git add .` adds the files of the current folder. Maybe you can check your last commit files.

Comment: What about .gitignore? Try to check that dir is not covered by any pattern

Comment: After the git add It showed that 6 files were changes to be committed and 8 files were not staged for commit.  Those 8 are already in the repository.  They're not ignored.  Then I did a commit, and then a status again.  The status showed a clean tree.

Comment: Can you check your last commit just to be sure?

Comment: I'm looking at my window where I did it.  Just one commit.  Is there a specific command you want me to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do the following to check your last commit and view the files you commited.

1. Ge tyour last commit id by running: `git log` and copy your last commit id, something like: `1016d545349886b958b671f57ba201e69f224445`.
2. List all the files in the commit: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r YOUR_COMMIT_ID` (change YOUR_COMMIT_ID with the value you get from step 1).

You should get a list of all the files you commited.

Adding all files with `git add -A` will add all the files in the working tree. So after you add your files, you can run `git status` before commit and be sure what files you will be commiting.

Comment: OK, I was looking at wrong branch on github site.  What I don't get though is why the status said they were NOT staged for commit, but then the commit actually took them.

Comment: Yes, that's strange. :\